# Vaadin treegrid conditional formatting

Tags: java, vaadin, conditional-formatting, vaadin8, treegrid

I am applying conditional highlighting to a TreeGrid, however, it does not apply the color to the row. I am using similar approach to Grid and it works flawlessly. Has anybody had similar issues with TreeGrid?

Code:

Trigger highlighting via Grid component button -

```
btnRed.addClickListener(clickEvent -> {
    if (isContained(selectedItems.keySet(), systemAccessDTO)){
        removeItemsRecursively(systemAccessDTO);
    }else {
        addItemsRecursively(systemAccessDTO);
    }
    updateStyles();
});
```

Updating style -

```
private void updateStyles() {
    grid.setStyleGenerator(systemAccessDTO -> {
        if (isContained(selectedItems.keySet(), systemAccessDTO)) {
            return "red";
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

PS: Vaadin version 8.4.3

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have found the problem. The Grid and TreeGrid classes in vaadin have different CSS classes. Posting this for anyone that has the same problem.

Styling the treegrid rows:

```
    .v-treegrid-row.treegrid_custom_style .v-treegrid-cell {
          background-color: #a8c9ff;
    }

    .v-treegrid-row-stripe.treegrid_custom_style .v-treegrid-cell {
          background-color: #a8c9ff;
    }
```